# Law of total expectation - a toss of a coin

Tags: probability

There is the following question: There is a coin with probability $p$ to be $H$ and $q$ to be $T$. I'm asked what is the expectation of the tossing number, considering I toss the coin until I get both $H$ and $T$. I thought I could do it the following way (X - number of coin tossing after the first toss):
$$E\left[X\right]=E\left[E\left[X\mid Y\right]\right]=p\left(\text{first toss is H}\right)\cdot E\left[X\mid\text{first toss is H}\right]+p\left(\text{first toss is T}\right)\cdot E\left[X\mid\text{first toss is T}\right]=p\cdot\frac{1}{q}+q\cdot\frac{1}{p}$$
as the random variable is distributed geometrically after the first toss.
The total number is then:
$$1+\frac{p}{q}+\frac{q}{p}$$

But that's not the answer. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: Seems alright to me. May be it was just written in a different form

Comment: Your answer looks fine.  What was the official answer?

Comment: Thank you! It was indeed written in a very different way, I was too insecure to even try to check.